# PowerShell - Set-Culture doesn't seem to change anything

Tags: powershell, azure, cultureinfo

I have a Cloud Service Web Role that I need to run some PowerShell on to ensure the server is always setup in the right culture: en-AU.

The reason for this is that Microsoft could, at anytime, reset the culture values.

When I run:

```
Get-Culture
```

I get:

```
1033             en-US            English (United States)
```

So then I run:

```
Set-Culture en-AU
```

But I still get:

```
1033             en-US            English (United States)
```

I have tried many things but nothing seems to really change the culture.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Changing user locale does not affect already started PowerShell instances. You have to start new PowerShell process, so it pickup new value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The root cause is because you are not running the PowerShell with **Administrator privilege**.

`Set-Culture` needs Administrator privilege to be set on the system.

Just run your PowerShell in Administrator mode and your culture will be set to the new one as below:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you were to run the PowerShell script in the Azure Cloud Service web role, I would recommend to add #Requires -RunAsAdministrator in your PowerShell script to make sure your PowerShell will have the elevated privilege to set culture

Comment: If the above able to resolve your issue, I will edit my answer.

Comment: What is the status of this issue? Is anymore support needed?

Comment: your answer was correct. So as far as I understand, I should always run powershell ISE as administrator?

Comment: @RuSs, thanks for your feedback. Yes I would recommend that if you intend to modify system settings

Comment: Thanks; changes took place immediately but I had to close and reopen the powershell terminal before `Get-Culture` to get the updated value.

Comment: For me its works only on PowerShell 7 (on windows server 2022).

Answer (score 5):

Like [petseral](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) said in a comment above:

> Changing user locale does not affect already started PowerShell instances.
>   You have to start new PowerShell process.

Comment: This is exactly the answer for me